# mysql joining 3 tables with sum gives wrong result

Tags: mysql, database, join, sum

I have been trying to make a balance sheet, using 3 tables. First table is names of suppliers. The second table for is due to suppliers and third table is payment to supplier, both connected with a foreign key with supplier table.

I am expecting a result like:

> supplier name-----------------------  due------------------------------- payment
>
> name------------------ sum (quantity*unitprice)
>   ------------------sum (pay amount)

My query is

```
SELECT 
    tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS supplier,
    SUM(tbl_payment.pay_amount) AS payment,
    SUM(tbl_stock.stock_qnt * tbl_stock.stock_up) AS due
FROM
    tbl_supplier
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_payment ON tbl_supplier.id = tbl_payment.supplier_id
        INNER JOIN
    tbl_stock ON tbl_supplier.id = tbl_stock.supplier_id
GROUP BY supplier_name
```

But the result is multiplying sum of due with the number of payment, and vice-versa.

For example, if a supplier has total due of 1000 and he has been paid 3 times, its showing total due is 3000, not 1000.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: have you trued DISTINCT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot `join` the stock and the payment-table. The `join` will combine every row in `tbl_payment` with every row in `tbl_stock`, so with 3 rows in `tbl_payment`, you would get the 1 original row in `tbl_stock` 3 times, and then sum over these. `Distinct` is NOT a solution, because it then ignores values that are, well, not distinct, e.g. if you actually have 2 payments of $100, you will have a distinct sum of $100 (since $100 and $100 are the same value).

You can use subquerys to calculate the sums separately (this is an implied `join` of `tbl_supplier` with `tbl_payment` and `tbl_supplier` with `tbl_stocks`, but not all three together):

```
SELECT 
   tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS supplier,
   (select sum(tbl_payment.pay_amount) 
    from tbl_payment 
    where tbl_payment.supplier_id = tbl_supplier.id) as payment,
   (select sum(tbl_stock.stock_qnt * tbl_stock.stock_up) 
    from tbl_stock
    where tbl_stock.supplier_id = tbl_supplier.id) as due
from tbl_supplier;
```

Comment: Thank you Solarflare. You are right. DISTINCT is not the solution as it does not count multiple same value. Your code seems to be working. Let me check it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

### solution as suggested by user5599807

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS supplier,
        SUM(DISTINCT tbl_payment.pay_amount) AS payment,
        SUM(DISTINCT tbl_stock.stock_qnt * tbl_stock.stock_up) AS due
    FROM
        tbl_supplier
            INNER JOIN
        tbl_payment ON tbl_supplier.id = tbl_payment.supplier_id
            INNER JOIN
        tbl_stock ON tbl_supplier.id = tbl_stock.supplier_id
    GROUP BY supplier_name
```

Comment: This will NOT work (at least not in general)! If you have the same payment amount several times, e.g. if you pay $100, $100 and $200, your distinct sum will be $300 (since you have the distinct (=different) values $100 and $200) . Same result if you order the same amount of products several times. You cannot join all 3 tables, but have to use subquerys. I'll add an answer.